# How can I assign a multiple column in my sql tables to single column in my List<>

Tags: c#, mysql, angularjs, linq

I have 3 tables in my sql as:-

Table1(ClassNote),Table2(ClassSamplePaper),Table3(ClassEbook) having PK as ClassNoteID, ClassSamplePaperID and ClassEbookID respectively.

Now I have a situation where I am passing their values to separate lists from my c# Controller to  Angular Controller.

My C# Code is:-

```
switch (dbundle.MaterialIndicator)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    List<ClassEbook> EBookList = null;
                                    EBookList = (from cl in db.ClsObj
                                                 join csr in db.ClassSubRelationObj on cl.ClassesID equals csr.ClassSubjectFK
                                                 join csmr in db.ClassSubMatRelationObj on csr.ClassSubjectFK equals csmr.SubjectFK
                                                 join eb in db.CebookObj on csmr.ClassEbookFK equals eb.ClassEbookID
                                                 where cl.ClassesID == dbundle.ClassesFK && csr.ClassSubjectFK == dbundle.ClassSubjectFK
                                                 select eb).ToList();
                                    return new JsonResult { Data = EBookList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                                case 2:
                                    List<ClassNote> NoteList = null;
                                    NoteList = (from cl in db.ClsObj
                                                join csr in db.ClassSubRelationObj on cl.ClassesID equals csr.ClassSubjectFK
                                                join csmr in db.ClassSubMatRelationObj on csr.ClassSubjectFK equals csmr.SubjectFK
                                                join cn in db.CNoteObj on csmr.ClassNoteFK equals cn.ClassNoteID
                                                where cl.ClassesID == dbundle.ClassesFK && csr.ClassSubjectFK == dbundle.ClassSubjectFK
                                                select cn).ToList();

                                    return new JsonResult { Data = NoteList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                                case 3:
                                    List<ClassSamplePaper> SPList = null;
                                    SPList = (from cl in db.ClsObj
                                              join csr in db.ClassSubRelationObj on cl.ClassesID equals csr.ClassSubjectFK
                                              join csmr in db.ClassSubMatRelationObj on csr.ClassSubjectFK equals csmr.SubjectFK
                                              join sp in db.CSPObj on csmr.ClassEbookFK equals sp.ClassSamplePaperID
                                              where cl.ClassesID == dbundle.ClassesFK && csr.ClassSubjectFK == dbundle.ClassSubjectFK
                                              select sp).ToList();
                                    return new JsonResult { Data = SPList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

And I fetch the List in my Angular Controller as:-

```
ClassFactory.AvailableListData($scope.MaterialTblID).then(function (d) {
            $scope.AvailableList = d.data;
            if ($scope.AvailableList != null && $scope.AvailableList.length != 0) {
                    $scope.AvailableListTextToShow = "";
                }
                else {
                    $scope.AvailableListTextToShow = "No Data Available";
                }
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Cannot Load AvailableList Data');
        })
```

The code is working fine! But I want to use a single field for my IDs from different tables. How can I achieve this?

Razor Syntax:-

```
 <tr ng-repeat="L in AvailableList">
                            <td>
                                {{$index+1}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{L.Heading}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{L.ID}} //I want to use it here
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Sorry if I didn't make the question clear. Feel free for commenting on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a `ViewModel` for display purposes, it would be a normal class that only has the `Heading` and `ID` properties on it (plus any others that you want to render out). In your controller you would have to map from your DB Model, to your ViewModel, or use something like AutoMapper and return this new "ViewModel" instead of `SPList`, `NoteList`, and `EBookList`.

An example would be:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Heading { get;set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public static class MyViewModelsExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<ListViewModel> ToEbookViewModels(this IQueryable<ClassEbook> classEBooks)
    {
        return classEBooks.Select(m => new ListViewModel { Heading = m.Heading, ID = m.ClassEbookID });
    }

    // TDOD: Add other ToViewModels methods to handle tranforming ClassNote and ClassSamplePaper models
}

// Inside controller action/where your current switch statement is
switch (dbundle.MaterialIndicator)
{
         case 1:
                var EBookList = (from cl in db.ClsObj......);
                List<ListViewModel> viewModelEbook = EBookList.ToEbookViewModels().Distinct().ToList();
                return new JsonResult { Data = viewModelEbook, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        case 2:
        case 3:
            // both of these will look similar to the above case handling except you will pass in IQueryable of ClassNote and ClassSamplePaper
}
```

I haven't done any work in Angular but assuming that you currently have it working using the `Data` attribute of the `JsonResult` then you shouldn't have to change anything..

Some further reading on the topic and merits of having separate domain/data models and view models can be found [here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/188/view-model-design-and-use-in-razor-views) and in pattern three [here](http://stevemichelotti.com/aspnet-mvc-view-model-patterns/). Yes the example references Razor but the principles are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. These two lines are giving me error:- List<ClassEBook> eBookList = (from cls....); // Remove the .ToList() call because we want an IQueryable
            List<MyViewModel> viewModels = eBookList.ToViewModels().ToList();

Comment: 1. Cannot convert from IQueryable to List. 2. 'List<ClassEbook>' does not contain a definition for 'ToEbookViewModels' and the best extension method overload 'ListViewModelExtender.ToEbookViewModels(IQueryable<ClassEbook>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<ClassEbook>'

Comment: @Deepak change the type of ebooklist to var and that should fix it.

Comment: Already did that. Edited your answer as well. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Deepak awesome, glad that I could be of assistance. :-)